# Can't find variable: Store

Tags: react-native

I'm working on an react-native app since 3 months, and we're currently using `v0.21`.

In an attempt to upgrade the app in order to fix a bug, I:

- ran `brew update && brew upgrade`
- Made some change to `package.json`
- ran `npm install`
- ran `npm update -g react-native-cli` to get the v0.1.10 locally

At this point I tried to run the app, but either in iOS or Android, I've got the same error:
[image: React native bug]

So Logically I got back to `origin/master`, remove my `node_modules` folder, and reinstalled the react-native-cli v0.1.7 ... But I've got the same error !!

My package.json looks like that:

```
{
  "name": "XXXXXX",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "awesome-phonenumber": "^1.0.10",
    "buffer": "^3.6.0",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "react-native": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-blur": "^0.7.10",
    "react-native-button": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "^1.5.3-beta",
    "react-native-date": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-drawer-layout": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-facebook-ios": "file:lib/react-native-facebook-ios",
    "react-native-facebook-login": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-floating-label-text-input": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.1.6",
    "react-native-material-kit": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "file:lib/react-native-onesignal",
    "react-native-parallax": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-parallax-scroll-view": "^0.16.17",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^2.2.6",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.3.5",
    "react-native-sync-now-android": "file:lib/react-native-sync-now-android",
    "react-native-sync-now-ios": "file:lib/react-native-sync-now-ios",
    "react-native-timer-ios": "file:lib/react-native-timer-ios",
    "react-native-twitter-ios": "file:lib/react-native-twitter-ios",
    "react-native-twitter-login": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-utils": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^0.1.5",
    "react-redux": "^3.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "rnpm": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "postinstall": "sh scripts/postinstall.sh"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-cli": "^0.1.7"
  }
}
```

I'm sure the problem is in the version of my tools because everything happened after I updated them and the code is the same

Here's the versions:

- `Watchman` 4.4.0
- `Flow` 0.22.1
- `react-native-cli` 0.1.7

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it !

Because I must have upgraded packagers, it did not like the:

```
export default variable = {};
```

It prefers:

```
const variable = {};
export default variable;
```

Lost 24 hours on this...